# At what points is the function $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
11 &  \text{if} \; 0 \le x <1\\ 
 x&  \text{if}\; 1<x \leq 2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
At what points is the function $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous

my idea: here $1$ is the point of discontinuity so $f$ is continuous every where except at $x=1$ correct?

Comment: You completed post graduate studies in maths and you're asking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get the right answer.

- For $0 \le x < 1$, a constant function is continuous.
- For $1 < x \le 2$, a polynomial is continuous.
- To prove that it is not continuous at $1$, try to take left hand side and right hand side limit and check that they are not equal.

Comment: ..thank you once again